# Ruby Inherit Class in the same module in 2 separates files

Tags: ruby

I would like to inherit a class the same module but in two separates files.

```
# file1.rb
module Module
  class A
  end
end
```

I try something and this works:

```
# file2.rb
class Module::B < Module::A
end
```

But it looks like weird.. no ?

Is this is the same as the example above ? I tested and it's not.. Why ?

```
# file2.rb
module Module
  class B < A
  end
end
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by 'this isn't working' ? Is it giving enexpected behaviour or  throwing error, if yes update question with error log

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I just want to know why the first example is not the same thing than the second..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by

> I tested and it's not [the same]

Because you didn't explain what unexpected result/difference you are seeing.

*However...*

Generally speaking, both versions of that code should behave exactly the same. There is only one subtle difference.

In this version:

```
module Module
  class B < A
  end
end
```

The class `A` will first try to resolve as `Module::A`, and then (if such a class is not found) it will try to resolve as `::A` (i.e. a top-level class).

Therefore the behaviour will be different only if `Module::A` does not exist/has not been loaded, and `::A` does exist and has been loaded.